# Clustered index always better than Non-Clustered index?

Tags: sql-server, clustered-index

When I have a clustered index on 'A', is it better to use this clustered index even if I have

selection of 'A=constant'? If not, why?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean "non-clustered" index? And what RDBMS too please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just want to put in a word of warning: please **very carefully** pick your clustered index!

It's the **most replicated** data structure in your SQL Server database (assuming it's SQL Server you're talking about). The clustering key will be part of each and every non-clustered index on your table, too - certainly in the leaf level, possibly also in the index navigation structure.

You should use extreme care when picking a clustering key - it should be:

- **narrow** (4 bytes ideal)
- **unique** (it's the "row pointer" after all - if you don't make it unique, SQL Server will - for you - in the background - costs your a couple of bytes for each entry - times the number of rows and the number of nonclustered indices you have - can be very costly!)
- **static** (never change - if possible)
- ideally **ever-increasing** so you won't end up with horrible index fragmentation (a GUID is the total opposite of a good clustering key - for that particular reason)
- it should be non-nullable and ideally also fixed with - a `varchar(250)` makes a very poor clustering key

Anything else should really be second and third level of importance behind these points ....

See some of Kimberly Tripp's (*The Queen of Indexing*) blog posts on the topic - anything she has written in her blog is absolutely invaluable - read it, digest it - live by it!

- [GUIDs as PRIMARY KEYs and/or the clustering key](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/GUIDs-as-PRIMARY-KEYs-andor-the-clustering-key.aspx)
- [The Clustered Index Debate Continues...](http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/The-Clustered-Index-Debate-Continues.aspx)
- [Ever-increasing clustering key - the Clustered Index Debate..........again!](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/Ever-increasing-clustering-key-the-Clustered-Index-Debateagain!.aspx)

Comment: http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Actually, I'm not sure how you would *not* use the index in this case. The clustered index contains the actual row data. That's why there can only be one clustered index. All non-clustered indexes contain pointers to the actual data.

So using the clustered index saves you doing a lookup from the index to the data.

Comment: Unless "covering" http://stackoverflow.com/a/1308012/27535

Comment: **IF** the user is really talking about SQL Server ..... (I'm assuming so, too - just not really confirmed yet)